# How to diaplay ROWID of a table in Fusion Table

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

I have a table named "Testing". Fields in this table are Id,Name and Description. Only these fields are shown in fusion table viewer. i also want to show ROWID for each row in fusion table viewer.Is it possible to show????

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you

```
<?php

include('../clientlogin.php');
include('../sql.php');
include('../file.php');

//get token
$token = ClientLogin::getAuthToken('username', 'password');
$ftclient = new FTClientLogin($token);

//select rowid from table
echo $ftclient->query(SQLBuilder::select(358077, array('rowid')));
echo "<br />";
```

Source:
[Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/source/browse/trunk/samples/client_login_example.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to see the rowid within Fusion Tables at this time. You can star the following feature request:

http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=859